# Require authentication or certificate to view Heroku app

Tags: heroku, oauth, credentials

I have an api deployed to Heroku.  It is currently open for everyone to see. I only want known android phones to be able to modify and access the api.

I don't want the user to have to login every time they use the app.

Can I add some sort of certificate to the phone to verify that it is credible?

Is OAuth the best approach for this?

Is there a better way to do this so the user doesn't have to login every time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly broad question (and hence there are several approaches). Without knowing the language/framework you are using it's also hard  to give specific advice, but:

- Your server can issue a cookie or token that the client can store locally for a duration. These tokens should include a timestamp and be authenticated (use a library that does HMAC authentication) to prevent clients from modifying tokens.
- Clients should present this token or cookie on each request to your server via a HTTP header or the standard `Cookie` header.
- You will need a login system to support the initial issue of the token/cookie.

Clients could also OAuth against your server (complex) or against an external service (GitHub/Facebook/Google/Twitter), but you will still need a way to track that state on the client (hence a token/cookie).

Cookie support should be included with the standard Android HTTP client, and most server side frameworks have support (or a library for) authenticated cookies.

Comment: Thank you.  I am using Django.  However, I am calling the rest api from an Android application.

Comment: If you're using Django, I'd suggest using [`django.contrib.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/) with signed cookies (simple) or considering token authentication from http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication